# CORS missmatch because of http

Tags: javascript, wordpress, nginx, server, cors

I don't understand why i get this error.

```
sub.domain.app/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.app/wc-api/v3. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'sub.domain.app'. Origin 'http://sub.domain.app' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The site domain.app is a wordpress install and sub.domain is just static html. And I the error occurs when i try to fetch via ajax (vue-router).

Both the domains are on homestead. And I have set up nginx to allow the subdomain to do CORS requests.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "http://sub.domain.app";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
}
```

I'm hoping someone smarter than me can help me solv this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work if you change `http://sub.domain.app` to `*` in the `add_header` statement? I don't suggest leaving it that way, but it may help to figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Yes, then it works. :)

Comment: What's the output of `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`? It looks like the rejected request is for `http://domain.app/wc-api/v3`, which would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to allow requests for the main domain *and* a subdomain. [CORS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) does not permit that in a single header. Either the exact domain or '*'. You have to dynamically check the domain and set *that* in the header.

**With NGINX:**

```
 server {

    root /path/to/your/stuff;

    index index.html index.htm;

     set $cors "";

    if ($http_origin ~* (.*\.domain.com)) {
        set $cors "true";
    }

    server_name domain.com;

    location / {

        if ($cors = "true") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type';
        }


        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            return 204;
        }

    }
}
```

[More here](http://rustyrazorblade.com/2013/10/cors-with-wildcard-subdomains-using-nginx/).

**With PHP**

Examine `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and search it for your desired (sub)domains, and then conditionally set your CORS headers with PHP.

So, something like this:

```
$allowed_hosts = array('sub.domain.app', 'domain.app');

if (in_array($allowed_hosts, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try It and get back to you! :)

Answer (score -1):

The page where you would like to get your result by ajax at the top of this page add the following :

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I only want to allow that specific subdomain. And it seams to be almost working, except the header omits the http:// part.